# Days between two dates and store in variable

Tags: swift, nsdate

How can i store the calculated days between two dates in a variable so i can store the "days" in CloudKit

My code are (working to calculate days between dates):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: datepicked, toDate: enddate, options: [])

    print("DAYS LEFT :" , components)
```

Result are :

```
DAYS LEFT : <NSDateComponents: 0x7fd399ccb890>
Day: 1095
```

Comment: What is both your date? and is the result correct?

Comment: The result are correct, but i want to store the value days between ex. "1095" in a variable

Comment: @vadian answer is correct. just `components.day` will do

Comment: Yes. @vadian answer works great :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on the variable `components` and then on `NSDateComponents` in the popup view.

In the documentation you can see that there is a property `day` to get the value of the `.Day` component.

> var day: Int

So simply write

```
let day = components.day
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I here have a piece of code which calculates the hours between two times in Objective-C. I'm sure you can rewrite this to make it days.

```
- (void)updateTimer {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    /* instead of conceptDate the date of the started and stopped time will be used when the database is edited so
     date is nog a seperate column but is included in the colums start and stop to display working times that exceed
     the 00.00 timestamp or take multiple days (for somewhat reason)*/

    NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self conceptDate], startedTime]];
    NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self conceptDate], [self getCurrentTime]]];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

    if( interval  < 0 ) {
        interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
    }

    int hours = (int)interval / 3600;             // integer division to get the hours part
    int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
    int seconds = (interval - (hours*3600) - (minutes*60)); // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes

    NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    _workingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeDiff];
 }
```

I hope this helps. Currently the time difference is stored in _workingTime object but can of course be stored in another string variable.

Comment: The date calculation using `NSCalendar` in the question is much more convenient and precise than doing date math with literal numbers. For example unlike `NSCalendar` `timeIntervalSinceDate` does not consider daylight saving changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get days between two days then you should try this.

```
 func daysFrom(FromDate:NSDate,ToDate:NSDate) -> Int{
    return  NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.Calendar.exclusiveOr(NSCalendarUnit.Day), fromDate: date, toDate: ToDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents).day
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
func days(from:Date,to:Date) -> Int {
    return  Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: from, to: to).day!
}
```